# Unable to load a model's relationship with Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

For a Laravel 7.3 project that I'm working on, I have two tables that look like follows (relevant part):

<sub><sup>("prestation" = "performance" in english)</sup></sub>

```php
Schema::create('prestations', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('title');
    $table->unsignedInteger('prestation_categories_id');
    ...
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

```php
Schema::create('prestation_categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('title');
    ...
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

This is how I set their relationship:

**Prestation.php**

```php
/**
 * @return BelongsTo
 */
public function categories ()
{
    return $this->BelongsTo('App\PrestationCategory');
}
```

**PrestationCategory.php**

```php
/**
 * @return HasMany
 */
public function prestations ()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Prestation');
}
```

Now, my Laravel is used as an API for an SPA that runs on the top of it, and displays its datas in JSON. I have a page that's meant to display all the datas, plus at least two fields of the performance's category. My goal is to have a JSON string that looks like so:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'Some title',
    description: 'Lorem ipsum sic amet...',
    category: { // or prestation_category, I don't care
      id: 2
      color: '#42B79CFF',
    },
    ...
  },
  {
    ...
  }
]
```

However, I'm having lots of trouble to load this related category.
I found countless questions about this subject, but oddly, none help.

Here is how I tried to setup my controller's action

```php
public function dashboard ()
    {
  // Try #1
  $prestation = Prestation::with('categories:id,color')->get();

  // Try #2
  $prestations = Prestation::with(['categories' => function ($query) {
    $query->select('color', 'whole_day');
  }])->get();

  // Try #3
  $prestations = Prestation::join('prestation_categories', 'prestations.prestation_categories_id', '=', 'prestation_categories.id')->get();

  return response()->json($prestations);
}
```

Each of these methods returns me my "Prestation", however, the related category isn't loaded.

Where did I do wrong, and how can I fix it?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Any change if you set scheme to be `$table->unsignedBigInteger('prestation_categories_id');`?

Comment: ... It worked. I kept the code from the third try, and I now find myself with both my fields from 'Prestation' and from 'PrestationCategory' !
Feel free to post your response, I'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default migration schema's id() field is big integer. So to keep having same constraint between related tables, you would use same field types.

```
// prestations
Schema::create('prestations', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('title');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('prestation_categories_id');// pay attention here
    ...
    $table->timestamps();
});

// prestation_categories
Schema::create('prestation_categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();// this field is unsigned big integer
    $table->string('title');
    ...
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Side note: although PHP allows case insensitiveness in function/method names, it is [belongsTo()](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasRelationships.php#L170) method. Try to stick with naming convention and best practices described [here](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices) and you'll skip lot of unforced errors.

Comment: I just renamed my model / migration / relationship and now it works as it should. Boy did I loose some hours with finding stupid table names. Thanks again!

Comment: We never stop learn. ;) As much as you stick with naming of Laravel's official docs and most of it (at least most used) is described in that GitHub link, you'll see big gain in productivity.